# My live app - Interstitial frequency capping for iphone is not working but is woking for iPad

Tags: swift, admob, interstitial

I launched my IOS app with AdMob interstitial ads, and it's live now. I set frequency capping, every 10 min, for the interstitial ads. When users are moving around by clicking buttons on the app, an ad is supposed to be shown every 10 min. But it is not working properly on iPhones, but is working properly on iPads. On iPads, it is working as I coded. Ads are shown based on the time (every 10 min), not based on clicking (every click). But on iPhones, ads are shown for every clicking, not based on the time (every 10 min.). I couldn't find any information about it and tried to contact AdMob. None of them helped me with this issue. Users started complaining about it. Should I code differently for iPhone and iPad (I don't think so but). Please help me.

[Admob Interstitial Ad Unit Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s7BW.png)

Comment: did you figure out what was the issue? I'm having the same problem